# How to disable custom animations from click, angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have Cordova application uses Ionic + Angular (Still 1.2.25)

I have my custom animations stored in one css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
```

This file has about 20 classes

In my application I have settings field Enable/Disable animation.

How can I disable loading of `animations.css` programmatically?

As alternative way, I thought to add some root class as prefix (lets say `.animate-flag`) to all animation classes for example:

```
  .wm-opacity-low-add, .wm-opacity-low-remove {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
   transition: 0.5s linear all;
  }

  .wm-opacity-low,
  .wm-opacity-low-add.wm-opacity-low-add-active {
   opacity: 0.4;
  }

  .wm-opacity-low-remove.wm-opacity-low-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

goest to be:

```
  .animate-flag.wm-opacity-low-add, .animate-flag.wm-opacity-low-remove {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
   transition: 0.5s linear all;
  }

  .animate-flag.wm-opacity-low,
  .animate-flag.wm-opacity-low-add.wm-opacity-low-add-active {
   opacity: 0.4;
  }

  .animate-flag.wm-opacity-low-remove.wm-opacity-low-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

and when user sets animation option `false` - remove `animate-flag` class from all DOM but it seems a bit messy.

Is there other gentle way to do the same job?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having all your animation stored in one single CSS file you could try to "disable" it like this:

```
<head>
  <link id="animations-css" rel="stylesheet" href="animations.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="remove-css">Remove CSS</button>
  <button id="add-css">Add CSS</button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('remove-css').addEventListener('click', function(){
      document.getElementById('animations-css').setAttribute('href', '');
    });

    document.getElementById('add-css').addEventListener('click', function(){
      document.getElementById('animations-css').setAttribute('href', 'animations.css');
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

It's kind of "dirty hack" but it should work :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ut3jLplacMctrrYIO6LP